# Partial Fraction Decomposition for the Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: partial-fractions, inverse-laplace

I need to do the inverse Laplace transform of such fraction: $$\frac{\frac{3}{9 + (-1 + p)^2}+p-3}{p^{2} -2p+10}$$. I've thought of rewriting it as $$\frac{\frac{3}{9 + (-1 + p)^2}+p-3}{p^{2} -2p+10}=\frac{\frac{3}{p^2 - 2p + 10}+p-3}{p^{2} -2p+10}=\frac{3}{(p^{2} -2p+10)^2}+\frac{p}{p^{2} -2p+10}-\frac{3}{p^{2} -2p+10}$$, but I don't know which original functions can I get from those fractions and stuck with that. Maybe there is a better way to expand it to particle fractions?

Tried using Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab to figure a solution for this - neither of them can show step by step solution.

Comment: The last two terms give sines and cosines when you complete the square in the denominator. The first... not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cfrac{\frac{3}{9+(-1+p)^2}+p+3}{p^2-2p+10}=\underbrace{\frac{3}{(p^2-2p+10)^2}}_{\color{red}{1}}+\underbrace{\frac{p+3}{p^2-2p+10}}_{\color{red}{2}}$$

---

Lets look at $\color{red}{2}$ first:
$$\frac{p+3}{p^2-2p+10}=\frac{(p-1)+4}{(p-1)^2+3^2}=\frac{(p-1)}{(p-1)^2+3^2}+\frac{4}{(p-1)^2+3^2}$$
Now you will want to make use of the fact that:
$$\mathscr{L}\left[e^{at}f(t)\right]\{s\}=\mathscr{L}[f(t)]\{s-a\}$$
or you may prefer to write it as:
$$\mathscr{L}[f(t)]=F(s),\,\,\mathscr{L}\left[e^{at}f(t)\right]=F(s-a)$$
which tells us that:
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{p-1}{(p-1)^2+3^2}\right]=e^t\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{p}{p^2+3^2}\right]=e^t\cos 3t$$

---

Now for the first one, using what we know before:
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{3}{((p-1)^2+3^2)^2}\right]=e^t\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{3}{(p^2+3^2)^2}\right]$$
so you just need to find the transform of this now.

---

Hint:
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{2a^3}{(s^2+a^2)^2}\right]=\sin at-at\cos at$$

Comment: Ok @Henry-Lee , But why do you write p+3 in the numerator? I have p-3

Comment: That is just a typo, but you can easily alter the method for your problem